# Racket difference between new and instantiate

Tags: object, racket, instantiation

On [table-panel](https://docs.racket-lang.org/table-panel/index.html) I stumbled upon the call to `instantiate`. Before, when reading the documentation for GUI in Racket I only saw `new` being used to create objects of GUI classes.

Usage of `instantiate` from that page:

```
(instantiate button%
        ((format "~a" j) child)
        (stretchable-width #t)
        (stretchable-height #t)
        (callback
         (lambda (button event)
           (printf "~a~n" (send button get-label)))))
```

Usage of `new` in the rest of the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html):

```
; Make a frame by instantiating the frame% class
(define frame (new frame% [label "Example"]))
```

What is the difference between the two?

## Edit

I found a [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objcreation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._instantiate%29%29) page telling me about the difference, but I don't really understand what "by-name initialization arguments" are. Is this the same as keyword arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(define frame (new frame% [label "Example"]))`, `[label "Example"]` is a by-name initialization argument, with the argument named being `label` being given the value `"Example"`. They're conceptually similar to keyword arguments but the mechanism is different and, unlike keyword arguments, they can be provided by position if you really want to. Here's the relevant docs, from https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html:

> Initialization arguments can be provided by name or by position. The
>   external name of an initialization variable can be used with
>   instantiate or with the superclass initialization form. Those forms
>   also accept by-position arguments. The make-object procedure and the
>   superclass initialization procedure accept only by-position arguments.
>
> Arguments provided by position are converted into by-name arguments
>   using the order of init and init-field clauses and the order of
>   variables within each clause. When an instantiate form provides both
>   by-position and by-name arguments, the converted arguments are placed
>   before by-name arguments. (The order can be significant; see also
>   Creating Objects.)

Comment: If I had only known about this kind of arguments before! In Python as in Racket I sometimes wanted to have by-name arguments it seems, only that I didn't know what they were called and that they actually exist in Racket.